# Using Debugger Visualizers in Visual Studio without having to copy its dll assembly to VS's folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debuggervisualizer

I know it is possible to create Debugger Visualizers since Visual Studio 2005.

Now, what I'd like to know is if it is possible to use our Debugger Visualizers without having to put them in Visual Studio's folder.

Although it is useful to have Visualizers for .NET's types as Bitmap, Image, arrays, etc, I wouldn't like to put in VS' folder Debugger Visualizers for types that only have meaning for my current project.

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered the [DebuggerTypeProxy] attribute?

Comment: What I really need is to show a kind of matrix, so DebuggerTypeProxy is of no avail.

Answer (score 7):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb2yca43.aspx) says it all:

To install a visualizer

1. Locate the DLL that contains the visualizer you have built.
2. Copy the DLL to either of the following locations:

   - InstallPath\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers
   - **My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Visualizers**
3. If you want to use the visualizer for remote debugging, copy the DLL to the same path on the remote computer.
4. Restart the Visual Studio debugging session.